# How do I implement my game from the system to a GUI? Java Code

Tags: java, user-interface, console

Hi people of StackOverflow, I'm fairly new to Java and need some help,
I have made a program that compiles how I want it, a guessing game whereby the computer randomly generates a number and the user is asked to guess it, this is all in the console however. I wish to create a GUI for the game, I have made the outline of the GUI in code but I am struggling to put the logic into it, am I better off calling the methods from the console program (and make some changes) or start from the top within in the GUI code and put the logic in there? If the latter, where do i put the logic? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are my two programs so far, both compile but the GUI is kind of meaningless right now!

Thank you in advance

This code is the console one, the user's guess is scanned and compared with the random number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGameSystem {
    public static int randomizer() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
        System.out.println(num);
        return num;
    }
    public static int userInput() {

        System.out.println("I've thought of a number between 1 and 10");
        System.out.println("Enter your guess...");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess = scan.nextInt();
        return guess;
    }
    public static String compare(int a, int b) {

        String result = null;
        if (a < b) {
            result = "Higher!";
        }
        else if (a > b)  {
            result = "Lower!";
        }
        else {
            result = "You guessed it - I was thinking of " + b;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(System.in);

        String playAgain = "";
        int count = 0;
        int a;
        int b;
        do  {
            b= randomizer();
            count = 0;
            ArrayList<Integer> guessesSoFar = new ArrayList<>();

            do {
                a = userInput();
                count++;
                guessesSoFar.add(a);
                System.out.println("Guesses so far: " + Arrays.toString(guessesSoFar.toArray()));
                System.out.println("Number of guesses so far: " + guessesSoFar.size());
                System.out.println(compare(a,b));       
            } while (a != b);
            System.out.println("It took you " + count + " guesses.");
            System.out.println("Play again? Yes/No");
            playAgain = scanLine.nextLine();
        } while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
}
```

And here is the GUI code I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GuessingGameGUI {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel lblInstructions, lblResult, lblGuesses, lblNoOfGuesses;
    private JButton btnCheck, btnNewGame, btnExit;
    private JTextField txtUserGuess, txtListOfGuesses, txtGuessesCount;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GuessingGameGUI();

    }
    public GuessingGameGUI() {
        createForm();
        createFields();
        createButtons();
        createTextField();

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void createForm() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Guessing Game");
        frame.setSize(800,350);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
    }
    public void createFields() {
        lblInstructions = new JLabel("Guess the number between 1 and 10:");
        lblInstructions.setBounds(285, 50, 350, 20);
        panel.add(lblInstructions);

        lblResult = new JLabel("Result");
        lblResult.setBounds(380, 200, 100, 20);
        panel.add(lblResult);

        lblGuesses = new JLabel("Your Guesses:");
        lblGuesses.setBounds(70, 50, 100, 20);
        panel.add(lblGuesses);

        lblNoOfGuesses = new JLabel("Number of Guesses:");
        lblNoOfGuesses.setBounds(600, 50, 200, 20);
        panel.add(lblNoOfGuesses);
    }

    public void createButtons() {
        btnCheck = new JButton("Check");
        btnCheck.setBounds(325, 150, 150, 20);
        panel.add(btnCheck);

        btnNewGame = new JButton("New Game");
        btnNewGame.setBounds(160, 300, 150, 20);
        panel.add(btnNewGame);

        btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.setBounds(495, 300, 150, 20);
        panel.add(btnExit);

        btnCheck.addActionListener(new CheckHandler());
        btnNewGame.addActionListener(new NewGameHandler());
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ExitHandler());
    }
    public void createTextField() {
        txtUserGuess = new JTextField();
        txtUserGuess.setBounds(300, 100, 200, 20);
        panel.add(txtUserGuess);

        txtListOfGuesses = new JTextField("List of Guesses");
        txtListOfGuesses.setBounds(65, 75, 115, 200);
        panel.add(txtListOfGuesses);

        txtGuessesCount = new JTextField("Guesses Count");
        txtGuessesCount.setBounds(610,75, 110, 20);
        panel.add(txtGuessesCount);
    }
    class CheckHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            //to check random number against user guess in txtUserGuess
        }
    }
    class NewGameHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            //to start a new game
         }
    }
    class ExitHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at MVP (Model View Presenter).

GUI code shouldn't have the game's logic – you shouldn't call methods that define the game's behaviour, only pass user commands forward.

Here's the outline of a possible way of implementing it using MVP (A > B means A calls B's method; the GUI is the View):

- User writes a number
- User presses "Check"

  - View > Presenter: `onCheckCommand(int number)`

    - Presenter > Model: `receiveGuess(int number)`

      - Model adds the received number to a list of guesses
      - Model returns `HIGHER`, `LOWER` or `RIGHT`
    - Presenter > Model: `getListOfGuesses()` and `getGuessesCount()`
    - Presenter > View: `showListOfGuesses(List<Integer> list)`, `showGuessesCount(int count)` and `showResult(Result result)` (`HIGHER`, `LOWER` or `RIGHT`)

      - View: If the result is `RIGHT`, disable the "Check" button
- User presses "New Game"

  - View enables the "Check" button and clears the result, list of guesses and guesses count
  - View > Presenter: `onNewGameCommand()`

    - Presenter > Model: `startNewGame()`

      - Model clears the list of guesses and generates a new number

Basically, the presenter is who knows which game methods should be called (and when) and what should be displayed (and when).
Model should have a public method for anything that happens (in the game) in response to user input or other external events, if any – for example, a timer that fires every second to update the remaining time.

I'm assuming the view forces the user to input integers. You should be careful to call methods that update the GUI [on the event dispatching thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#package.description). This already happens in this example, since all methods are called when handling the "button pressed" events. Calling everything from the handlers doesn't always work.